# Salir de la ejecución de una secuencia PHP y que siga la carga del HTML

Tags: php, html5

En el index.php hago lo siguiente:

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'includes/conexion.php';
include 'includes/funcs.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION["id_usuario"])){ //Si no ha iniciado sesión redirecciona a index.php
  $sinSesion = 1;
} else {
  $sinSesion = 2;
}

$idUsuario = $_SESSION['id_usuario'];
$sql = "SELECT id, nombre, usuario, clase FROM usuarios WHERE id = '$idUsuario'";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

$campo = 'nrologins';
$clase = 'clase';
$campoWhere = 'id';
$valor = $idUsuario;
$valorDevuelto = getValor($campo, $campoWhere, $valor);

if($valorDevuelto==0) { 
header("Location: forms/perfil/perfilusuario.php");
} 
?>
```

Esto es a la entrada del index.php. ¿Qué es lo que quiero hacer? Cuando entra a la página, verifica que si esta logueado el usuario y si éste está logueado coloca un menu con funciones personalizadas. Si no esta logueado, es decir, todavía no ingresó al sistema, carga un menú básico que no tiene tantas opciones. 
Ahora bien, quiero que cuando `$sinSesion` es igual a 1 salga del resto de la ejecución de ese tramo del codigo y siga con la carga del resto del html.

¿Está bien pensado o es muy rebuscado?

Quiero aclarar que el menu lo cargo aparte con un `include 'menu.php'`. ¿Me convendrá hacer esta comprobación en el `index.php`, o mejor en el `menu.php` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En vez de guardar el resultado de tu verificación de si esta iniciada la sesión en una variable, puedes de una vez ejecutar el código que quieras una vez probado de que si esta iniciada la sesión. Algo así:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION["id_usuario"]))
{
    $idUsuario = $_SESSION['id_usuario'];
    $sql = "SELECT id, nombre, usuario, clase FROM usuarios WHERE id = '$idUsuario'";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);

    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

    $campo = 'nrologins';
    $clase = 'clase';
    $campoWhere = 'id';
    $valor = $idUsuario;
    $valorDevuelto = getValor($campo, $campoWhere, $valor);

    if($valorDevuelto==0) { 
        header("Location: forms/perfil/perfilusuario.php");
    } 
}
```

Esta parte de tu comparación es el equivalente a decir que `$sinSesion` es igual a 1. Así que solo cuando eso sea verdad ejecutará este código. Si no, directamente pasa a lo demás, lo cual supongo que es la carga de tu html.

Si la variable `$sinSesion` te sirve en alguna otra parte de tu código, aun puedes guardar esa información allí y hacer una comparación extra.

```
if($sinSesion)
{
    //Codigo cuando si hay alguien que ha iniciado sesion. 
}
```

Comment: muy buena idea !!!... Gracias Kenny !!!

Comment: De nada, que bueno que te ha servido. Saludos!